# Image not loading after changing URL

Tags: php, html, xampp

I added this one to my index.php with a complete link of
http://localhost/DMS/index.php

the code is:

```
<a href="index.php/check-available-units">Check availability</a>
```

after clicking the link, it redirects me to
http://localhost/DMS/index.php/index.php/check-available-units
and the image is broken.

What I'm trying to do is get the string after the last '/' so I can have a clean-looking URL. Just like Facebook (facebook.com/yoursernamelink)

Any ideas on how to resolve this? thank you in advance! Happy coding!

Comment: It's not really clear to me. You're trying to link `DMS/index.php` to `DMS/check-available-units`? If so, please provide us with code. Did you set up any `.htaccess` files? Are you redirecting with JavaScript or using `<a>` tags? What's the `href` string you're trying to use?

Comment: Sounds like you need a routing engine like you get in Laravel and other frameworks